# Removing Attributes via Excel Import

Tags: excel, import, attributes, export, akeneo

I've recently been added to my team of Akeneo users because of my expertise with data management in Excel.  The most recent ask was that I remove some of the irrelevant attributes from specific items or item families, but not globally.  My colleague vaguely remembers something about a "blank" code or tag being used to do this, but he couldn't be more specific, and I wasn't able to find anything about it in the Akeneo documentation.  Anyone have any idea how to do this, or if it's even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the attribute values for specific products? or the attribute itself from a product family or the Akeneo system? If you want to remove an attribute from a product family, you would need to do that in the Akeneo UI or API, not via an Excel/CSV import.